# Dual Boot (Win10, Ubuntu 18.04 on NVME SSD) Can no longer boot on win10 (unable to run chkdsk)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, ssd, windows-10

I would really appreciate your help.
As the title, Laptop with dual boot on (Win10, Ubuntu 18.04 on NVME SSD) Can no longer boot on win10 (so unable to run chkdsk). Also tried boot-repair, supergrab2disk and rescatux with no luck. Ubuntu works and I can also access the file folder of OS Windows.

I attached 2 images, 1 from boot-repair.

Many thanks in advance for the help.

[image]

[image: Gparted]

Comment: Do not post image, post link to Summary Report from Boot-Repair. Can you directly boot Windows from UEFI menu? Grub only boots working Windows, so you have to boot Windows either from UEFI or from your Windows repair/recovery disk. Windows likes to turn fast start up back on with updates & then grub will not boot it.

Comment: Hello oldfred, thanks very much for the reply. I did try to boot from UEFI menu but it does not work. Any other idea :) ?

Comment: Then that is a Windows issue and this is an Ubuntu question & answer site. Try: https://superuser.com/ or https://www.tenforums.com/ You can only fix a very few Windows issues from Linux.

Comment: Thanks once more for the reply. But the thing is that I only have linux access right now so if anyone has any good idea, I would appreciate that.

Comment: To your knowledge, would there be another ubuntu related tool or way to fix my issue? Thanks

Comment: You already tried the others, that I know. There are a lot of third party Windows repair tools or you can just download the full Windows ISO which now is difficult to make bootable from anything other than Windows and use its repair console. Not sure if there is a download of just a repair/recovery image. That is something all users should immediately make & regularly refresh with Windows updates. Are you directly booting & pressing f8 (I think) to get into Windows internal repair console?

Comment: Cannot get into any windows related environment. I can only get into ubuntu and bios. Thanks for your help :)